# Show $\int_0^A \int_0^A \frac{1+(s-t)^2}{1+a^2(s-t)^2} e^{i (t-s) } dt ds\ge 0$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

How to show that 
\begin{align}
\int_0^A  \int_0^A  \frac{1+(s-t)^2}{1+a^2(s-t)^2} e^{i  (t-s) } dt ds \ge 0
\end{align}
for $a>1$ for all $A>0$.

Note the the above integral is real since the function
\begin{align}
f(t-s)= \frac{1+(s-t)^2}{1+a^2(s-t)^2}
\end{align}
is symmetric.

So, in fact we have to show that

\begin{align}
\int_0^A  \int_0^A  \frac{1+(s-t)^2}{1+a^2(s-t)^2} cos(t-s) dt ds \ge 0
\end{align}

Comment: A complex quantity cannot be ordered.  If the integral of interest is to be non-negative, then it must be purely real.  Can you show this to start?

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes, you have a point. No, I can not show that it is real, but I tried some numerical simulations and appear to be real. Does it follow since $\frac{1+x^2}{1+a^2x^2}$ is symmetric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By parity of the involved function, if $T$ is the region given by $0\leq y \leq x \leq A$,
$$ I=\iint_{(0,A)^2}\frac{1+(s-t)^2}{1+a^2(s-t)^2}\cos(t-s)\,ds\,dt = 2\iint_{T}\frac{1+(x-y)^2}{1+a^2 (x-y)^2}\cos(y-x)\,dx\,dy$$
and by a change of variable:
$$ I = 2 \int_{0}^{A}(A-u)\cos(u)\frac{1+u^2}{1+a^2 u^2}\,du. $$
Assuming $A\leq \pi$, the claim now follows from the [second mean value theorem for integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Second_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals):
$$ I = 2 \int_{0}^{B}(A-u)\cos(u)\,du, \qquad B\in[0,A] $$
where the last constraint ensures:
$$ I = 2(1-\cos B)+2(A-B)\sin(B) \geq 0. $$
If $A>\pi$, we may re-group terms in the resulting integral according to the periodicity of the cosine function and apply (essentially) the same argument.

---

Alternative (and cleaner) solution. By the properties of the [Fejér kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel), if $\omega(x)$ is an even function with a non-negative Fourier cosine transform, then
$$ \int_{0}^{A}(A-u) \omega(u)\geq 0. $$
On the other hand, if two even functions have non-negative Fourier cosine transforms, so does their product. $\cos(u)$ and $1$ trivially have non-negative Fourier cosine transforms, and the Fourier cosine transform of $\frac{1}{1+a^2 u^2}$ is given by $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{e^{-s/a}}{a}\geq 0$. It follows that by considering $\omega(u) = \cos(u)\frac{1+u^2}{1+a^2 u^2}$ the claim is trivial.

Comment: can you explain the change of variable part a little more?

Comment: @Boby: the last integral in the first line is the integral of a function of $(x-y)$: just set $(x-y)=u$ and the triangle $T$ is mapped into a (weighted) segment.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also give some more detail for $A>\pi$. Especially, about the regrouping.

Comment: @Boby: if $A>\pi$, $$\int_{0}^{A}(A-u)\cos(u)\omega(u)\,du = \int_{0}^{\pi}(A-u)\cos(u)\omega(u)\,du - \int_{0}^{A-\pi}(A-\pi-u)\cos(u)\omega(u+\pi)\,du. $$

Comment: There should be a plus between the first and second integral, right?

Comment: @Boby: nope, since $\cos(\pi+u)=-\cos(u)$.

Comment: Ok. Final question, why did we have to restrict to case $A>pi$ and $A<\pi$. Since, \begin{align} \int_0^A(A-u) cou(u) \phi(u) du = \phi(0)  \int_0^b(A-u) cou(u)  du  \end{align} . Is in $ \int_0^b(A-u) \cos(u)  du$ always positive?

Comment: @Boby: the initial restriction to $A\leq \pi$ is due to the fact that $2(1-\cos B)+2(A-B)\sin(B)$ is for sure non-negative only if $B\in[0,\pi]$. If $A\leq \pi$, then $B\leq \pi$ and no adjustments are needed. Otherwise, we need to perform some regrouping in order to avoid dealing with potentially negative contributes.

Comment: Never mind, I see it now $(A-b)sin(b)+(1-cos(b))$ can be negatie without restriction of $A$.

Comment: One more question. How do you know that the second integral is now not larger than the first one?

Comment: @Boby: by using a step of integration by parts ;)

Comment: So, it seems to meet the method you proposed works for any function $\omega$ as long as it is monotone decreasing and non-negative, right?

Comment: @Boby: if $\omega$ is bounded, decreasing and non-negative, under the assumption $A\leq \pi$ we may perform the same steps, exactly. I am not so sure the same trick works for unbounded $\omega$s, too, and there might be some issues in performing the "rearrangement" for $A>\pi$, anyway.

Comment: Do you think that would be  a good question to ask on the site?

Comment: @Boby: sure, why not?

Comment: Done. Posted it here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2056213/show-that-int-0a-a-x-cosx-fx-dx-ge-0-for-fx-monotone-decreasin